# Binomial distribution not adding up

Tags: probability

Suppose that there are 730 people in the class and each person’s
birthday is equally likely to be any of the 365 days in the year (for this question you should ignore
leap years).

Define $X1$ be the random variable corresponding to the number of people born on the
first day of the year.

Similarly, for $i = 2, 3, . . . , 365$, define $Xi$ to be the number of people born on
the $ith$ day of the year.

So each $Xi$ takes a value in the range {0, 1, . . . , 730} and, for example,
$$P(X1 = 10) = 
{730\choose{10}}

 \frac{1}{365}^{10} \frac{364}{365}^{720}$$

I realize that this is a Binomial distribution. Now:

Let X = X1 + X2 + . . . + X365

$$E(X) = 730$$

$$ var(X) = 0$$

why is E(X) = 730? I thought that in a binomial, the $E(X) = Np$, which in this case would be $\frac{730}{365}$

Comment: Pay attention to what $E[X]$ represents.  It represents the expected total number of people born on the first day *or* the second day *or* the ... *or* the 365th day.  In other words, $E[X]$ represents the total number of people.  Since there are $730$ people regardless how the birthdays are distributed, the expected value is identically $730$.  Since it is *always* $730$, the variance is zero.

Comment: $E[X_i]$ on the other hand is the expected number of people born on the $i^{th}$ day.  $E[X_i]$ is *not* the same thing as $E[X]$.  Indeed, $E[X_i]$ will be $\frac{730}{365}$ for exactly the reason you state, it is a binomial distribution.  $X_i$ is a binomial distribution, $X$ is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n$ are iid $\text{Bin}(n_i,p)$, then
$$Y = Y_1+\dotsb+Y_n\sim\text{Bin}\left(\sum_i n_i, p\right)$$

Notice, that $Y_i$ are ***iid***. Your $X_i$ are ***not*** iid, and $X$ is deterministic, 
$$X = X_1+\dotsb+X_{365} = 730$$
since each person is born on a particular day during the year. In other words, the number of people born in the year is $730$.

Hence
$$E[X] = E[730] = 730,$$
and $$\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(730) = 0.$$